# issue with CGI::unescapeHTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding, cgi

```
CGI::unescapeHTML("&#28195;&#25171;&#38134;")
```

=> "渣打\351\223\266"

```
CGI::unescapeHTML("&#28195;&#25171;&#38134; ")
```

=> "渣打银 "

Adding a space at the end makes the difference, else the last character is lost and I get this strange character sequence. I am facing this very issue when I try to scrape data form websites using utf-8 character encoding. This is true even for normal english text.

Comment: On my machine (ruby 1.9.2, no rails) your first line (without the space) works fine.

Comment: oh.. my ruby version is: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux] . Maybe I need to upgrade. Lemme try that.

Comment: On my machine (ruby-1.8.7-p334) it does not work at all without rails. Nevertheless, your first line works perfectly with ruby-1.8.7-p334 and rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with the `CGI` library that comes with Ruby 1.9.2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Run your ruby interpreter with -Ku